# Should number of applications and number of peer nodes be equal?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was reading the documentation of hyperledger (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/network/network.html) and I have a question from this paragraph

> We can see that the careful addition of peers to the network can help support increased throughput, stability, and resilience. For example, more peers in a network will allow more applications to connect to it; and multiple peers in an organization will provide extra resilience in the case of planned or unplanned outages.

Does the sentence `more peers in a network will allow more applications to connect to it` mean that one application should be communicating with one peer node and thus number of nodes should be equal to the number of applications on the channel?

If so why can't multiple applications just communicate directly to one node instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of planning to create a peer, you will need to consider your strategy at an organization level in order to ensure zero downtime of your components. This means building redundant components, and specifically redundant peers. To ensure zero downtown, you need at least one redundant peer in a separate virtual machine so that peers can go down for maintenance while client applications go on submitting endorsement proposals uninterrupted.

Along similar lines, client applications should be configured to use Service Discovery to ensure that transactions are only submitted to peers that are currently available. As long as at least one peer from each organization is available, and service discovered is being used, any endorsement policy will be able to be satisfied. It is the responsibility of each organization to make sure their high availability strategy is robust enough to ensure that at least one peer owned by their organization is available at all times in every channel they’re joined to.

Comment: so this means that the number of smart contracts installed on nodes is not necessarily equal right? But it is better to store on more than one node for redundancy to minimize downtime?